# How to restore MSDE database to last backup

Tags: backup, restore, msde

we have a huge (17 gig) MSDE backup file that have discovered has been appending nightly for the last 4 years.

We had a database failure last night and now we need to restore the database. 
We tried a standard restore but it restored the database info all the way back to 2008. Which isnt an accurate reflection of the state of the database as it was last backed up.

How do we restore back to just the last backup (or even a date/time) and not all the way back to 2008?

cheers
Buzz

Answer (score 0):

openthe log file, findout the date of the backup you want then use the script

RESTORE DATABASE [restoretest] FROM  DISK = N'C:\folder\backfile.bak' WITH  FILE = 1494
GO

hurray a working answer.

Buzz